# Oracle Apex 18.1 multiple charts based on one query/function

Tags: charts, oracle-apex

Is it possible to generate multiple charts based on changing parameter in select list of query using pipelined table? There are four parameters (**ID, account number, date from, date to**).

Sql query looks like this:

```
select * from  table(days_of_being_late_pkg.f_days_late_calendar(
      i_cli_id          => (Select id from clients where id_num = :CHOICE_ID)
     ,i_acc_num         => **:ACC_NUM**
     ,i_date_from       => :CALENDAR_FROM
     ,i_date_to         => :CALENDAR_TO
));
```

The task is to create a line chart based on above parameters and it works if I select the acc_num from select list, but the other part of the task is to generate multiple charts when the acc_num is not selected, taking as many **acc_num** parameters as there are for particular **i_cli_id.**
The chart shows how many days client is being late.

I hope it was clear enough.

Thank you in advance,
Josko

Comment: What is the maximum number of acc_num values per i_cli_id? You might have to create that number of regions and conditionally display them.

Comment: There is no limit as how many acc_num can one i_cli_id hold, but usually is up to 10, so there should be as many charts as there are acc_num values for each i_cli_id.

Comment: With no limit, this could be difficult. You could pick, say 15, and create 15 chart regions that are conditionally displayed. But if that number is ever exceeded, you'll need to create more. It's not ideal.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but i did a count query and there are clients with more than 100 acc_num so it would not be the best solution.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. In this case, you could write a custom, dynamic solution, but it would require a fair amount of JavaScript knowledge to create and maintain. Of course, for those clients with more than 100 acc_nums, I start to wonder how useful the charts would be anyway. Would anyone really look at 100 charts? Perhaps you could consider a UI change that prevents you from having to do something custom. For example, you could allow users to select up to x acc_nums to see charts.

Comment: Thank you for your help. What do you think about this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38091074/dynamic-chart-regions-in-oracle-apex , would it be possible to use :ACC_NUM instead of fixed values like in example?

Comment: Yeah, that's the kind of custom solution I was describing. Note there's a lot of custom JavaScript and HTML. If you're comfortable customizing that solution to meet your needs, then have at it! :)